# Perrin numbers in terms of the generalized hypergeometric function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, recurrence-relations

Given the roots of $x^3=x^2+1$, we have sequence [A001609](https://oeis.org/A001609),

$M(n) = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n = \,_3F_2\left(\frac{-n}{3}, \frac{1-n}{3}, \frac{2-n}{3};\; \frac{1-n}{2}, \frac{2-n}{2};\; -\frac{3^3}{2^2}\right) = 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15, 21,\dots$

for $n = {1,2,3,\dots}$

*Question*: Given $y^3=y+1$, is there any *similar* generalized hypergeometric formula for the [*Perrin numbers*](https://oeis.org/A001608)?

$P(n) = y_1^n+y_2^n+y_3^n = 0,2,3,2,5,5,7,10,\dots$

The closest I found is the binomial sum,

$ \begin{aligned}P(n) &= n\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{\binom k{n-2k}}{k} = 0,2,3,2,5,5,7,10,\dots\end{aligned}$

where both start with $n = 1,2,3,\dots$ Anyone knows how to translate that into the generalized hypergeometric function?

Comment: The Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrin_number) notes that P(n) can be computed in log(n) multiplies.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for calculating P(n) when n is prime using the hypergeometric function can be found at Perrin088.org (Chapter 15)

[image: hypergeometric function and Perrin(n)]

This equation is derived from an incomplete beta function giving the nth term of the Perrin sequence when n is prime.

Comment: How come google can't find Perrino88.org?

Comment: The site is Perrin088.org